# Arrayformula in google sheet

Tags: date, if-statement, google-sheets, concatenation, nested-if

I don't know how to fix this function to make it work. Every time it returns #N/A.
In column D I have a surname and in C I have first name

```
=ArrayFormula(
  IFS(
    ROW(B:B)=1; "Pattern";   
    LEN(B:B)=0; IFERROR(1/0);
    ISDATE(B:B)=True; LOWER( CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(D:D;"."); LEFT(C:C;1)))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in row 1:

```
={"Pattern"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISDATE_STRICT(B2:B); LOWER(D2:D&"."&LEFT(C2:C; 1)); ))}
```